# Let $F, F'$ be forests on the same vertex set with $E(F)<E(F')$. We have to show that $F'$ has an edge $e$ such that $F+e$ is again a forest.

Tags: graph-theory

This question is a question from the Graph Theory book of Diestel (exercise 1.22).

I thought I could solve it by first proving that $F$ has more connected components than $F'$ since $E(F)<E(F')$ which is not that hard. Then we know that there always exists an edge that could function as a bridge for $F$ so that $F+e$ is again a forest (with connected component less than $F$). I only have difficulties in proving that this bridge $e$ is in $F'$.

I thought maybe someone could help me with this problem.

Comment: Is it allowed to have $e\in F \cap F‘$?

Comment: I do not think so since then $F+e$ is the same as $F$ and then it is trivial

Answer (score 2):

Recall that any tree on $n$ vertices has $n-1$ edges, and any acyclic graph on $n$ vertices has at most $n-1$ edges.

Going off of your idea, let $F_1, F_2, \dots, F_k$ be the components of $F$, with $n_1, n_2, \dots, n_k$ vertices and $n_1 -1, n_2 -1, \dots, n_k - 1$ edges. In total, $|E(F)| = n_1 + \dots + n_k - k$.

Then $F'$ can only have at most $n_i - 1$ edges with both endpoints in $V(F_i$): if there were $n_i$ such edges, they'd form a cycle. So the total number of such edges (edges in $E(F')$ whose endpoints are in the same component of $F$) is also at most $n_1 + \dots + n_k - k$.

But we know $|E(F')| > |E(F)|$, so $F'$ has more edges than that. Therefore it must have an edge whose endpoints are in *different* components of $F$, and that's the bridge you wanted.